# Spring batch FlatFileItemReader read multiple files

Tags: spring-batch

As per [spring batch docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) they don't recommend using MuliResourceItemReader because of restart issue and recommend to use one file in each folder.

> "It should be noted that, as with any ItemReader, adding extra input
>   (in this case a file) could cause potential issues when restarting. It
>   is recommended that batch jobs work with their own individual
>   directories until completed successfully."

If I have a folder with following structure dest/<`timestamp`>/file1.txt, file2.txt

How do I configure FlatFileItemReader to read a file with pattern for each folder in a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration/) project for reading files from a directory since it is not Spring Batch Framework's business to poll a directory.

In the most basic scenario, Spring Integration will poll the files in the directory, and for each file it will run a job with the filename as a parameter. This will leave out the file polling logic from your batch jobs.

I should suggest this [excellent article](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/02/15/practical-use-of-spring-batch-and-spring-integration/) by [Dave Syer](http://blog.springsource.org/author/dsyer/) for the basic concepts of integrating these two technologies. Take a close look at the sections dealing with [FileToJobLaunchRequestAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/admin/integration/FileToJobLaunchRequestAdapter.html)

[Source code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/integration/FileToJobLaunchRequestAdapter.java) of this adapter will also help understanding the internals.

Answer (score 1):

I also got a similar set of requirement to read multiple text/csv files and achieved by using org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.

The detailed implementation is provided in the below link.

http://parameshk.blogspot.in/2013/11/spring-batch-flat-file-reader-reads.html